# sending a post request from android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, request

I have been struggling for hours now. I have been trying to make a post request from my android application. I figured out that i can't just make a request from the main thread, so i found out that i can put it in a thread runnable. I snooped around for answers tried out a lot of methods people used, that worked for others and none of them worked for me. The one I kind of understood was this one(doesn't work for me):

```
package com.example.matt.event;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class lokacije extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lokacije);
    thread.start();
}

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // replace with your url
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.awesomeholidays.com/login.php");


            //Post Data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "123"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "456"));


            //Encoding POST data
            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.d("omg it doesn't work",e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //making POST request.
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                // write response to log
                Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // Log exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Log exception
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
    }
});
}
```

I allowed it to get acces to internet so:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

The server side script api works, as i am just using it in a web app.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? I am clueless. Where could be the error? Perhaps the error is in my gradle?(I had to download the http libraries from apache.com and include the in my gradle - had to add a dependency compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5' and a bunch of packagingOptions {

```
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'

    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'

    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'

    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
```

})Is there an easy way? Also found out about the okhttp library, I'm going to try to implement it, but i'm really not good with gradle and importing foreign libraries.

This is what i get:

```
 11-28 20:49:49.587 10450-10450/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
 11-28 20:49:50.008 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
 11-28 20:49:50.008 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
 11-28 20:49:50.008 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14051: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
 11-28 20:49:50.008 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
 11-28 20:49:50.018 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
 11-28 20:49:50.018 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14055: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
 11-28 20:49:50.018 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
 11-28 20:49:50.238 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
 11-28 20:49:50.248 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13952: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
 11-28 20:49:50.248 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
 11-28 20:49:50.268 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
 11-28 20:49:50.268 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 402: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
 11-28 20:49:50.268 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
 11-28 20:49:50.278 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
 11-28 20:49:50.278 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 424: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
 11-28 20:49:50.278 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer D/dalvikvm: VFY:replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
 11-28 20:49:50.438 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
 11-28 20:49:50.458 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer D/libEGL:  loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
 11-28 20:49:50.458 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
 11-28 20:49:50.498 10450-10454/com.example.matic.eventer D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 198K, 9% free 9534K/10375K, paused 3ms+32ms, total 128ms
 11-28 20:49:50.518 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
 11-28 20:49:54.722 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 11-28 20:49:54.722 10450-10450/com.example.matic.eventer E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 11-28 20:49:56.514 10450-10583/com.example.matic.eventer D/Http Post Response:: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@417e0af0
```

Please help. :)
All the help is very appreciated.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552242/sending-http-post-request-with-android

Comment: Learn about volley library [in this awesome tutorial!](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/) It will make your life easier.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your error.
But for your question :

> Is there an easy way? Also found out about the okhttp library,

[Comparison of Android Networking Libraries: OkHTTP, Retrofit, Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley) is the beautiful post that compares all the available network libraries on every factor. Never think of framing the headers, body and parsing the responses on your own. Also retry, cancel-ongoing-requests, caching etc all are very easily done through libraries. And Retrofit tops on every factor. We are using it and it is good. It supports JSON, XML, Jackson, Moshi, Protobuf and also Wire data formats. All you need to do is to create request Body model classes, and response models. Take a look at [Retrofit beginner doc](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Answer (score 0):

OK. First of all thank you all for answering. :) It helped a lot. I just imported the okhttp library into the project and i will work with this from now on. Seems easy enough. Thanks again.

May the code be with you all!

Sincerely, 
Matic