# How to call the post method of a servlet?

Tags: java, android, servlets, httpclient

Am I able to create an object of the servlet and call the post method and pass the required arguments or do I have to declare it inside the web.xml and if I do declare it inside the web.xml file, do I still have to create an object from the servlet, how does this work? 
Im trying to use Google Cloud Storage, I already compiled the dependency in one of my modules, I also have the servlet class provided by google. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a servlet, it comes with two common methods, GET & POST

```
public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet{  
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException  {

    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

}
```

The easy way of calling a post method from html page is:

```
<form action="/servlet" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="q" value="a">
</form>
```

Comment: How do we call it from an Android application?

Comment: Please go to this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552242/sending-http-post-request-with-android