# Why i can't get the json data?

Tags: android

I use post man to test the url  (post), it looks fine. 
API:http://www.dmapp.com.tw/MobileApp/GetHealthData.php

But when i try it on my android , i can't get the message even my response code is 200

My logcat shows `{"Msg":"Request method not accepted","JsonData":null,"ErrorCode":"0099"}`

I do not get it , i used the code to get the json data well before.

Some one can teach me what step i miss it , that would be appreciated.

Here is my get json data function:

```
private String getRoute(String url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        StringBuilder jsonIn = new StringBuilder();
        // responseCode show 200
        Log.d("responseCode:",responseCode+"");
        if (responseCode == 200) {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonIn.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, responseCode + "responseCode");
        }
        connection.disconnect();
        // I can't get the json data it shows Request method not accepted
        Log.d(TAG, jsonIn + "jsonIn");
        return jsonIn.toString();

    }
```

Comment: The link you have linked has this error message too.

Comment: Thanks i get the answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HttpURLConnection is sending a GET request by default.
Your link is working perfectly.
Try adding
`connection.setRequestMethod("POST");`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552242/sending-http-post-request-with-android)

Comment: Thank you Sam !  You save me !

Answer (score 1):

The response from server itself is null as JsonData, You should check at server side.

Answer (score 1):

Hello your Link is working its just that its a **Post** Request

```
private String getRoute(String url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");


        StringBuilder jsonIn = new StringBuilder();
        // responseCode show 200
        Log.d("responseCode:",responseCode+"");
        if (responseCode == 200) {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonIn.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, responseCode + "responseCode");
        }
        connection.disconnect();
        // I can't get the json data it shows Request method not accepted
        Log.d(TAG, jsonIn + "jsonIn");
        return jsonIn.toString();

    }
```

I hope it will work But In My opinion you should work with Volley or Retrofit instead of HttpURLConnection